# Why isn't `catch` catching this exception?

Tags: haskell

I have a Servant app and an endpoint that creates a record in a database, then attempts to copy a file between S3 locations.  If the copy fails, I want to roll back the transaction.  I have this operator

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}    

import Control.Monad.Catch
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.Logger

(<??)
  :: (MonadError e m, MonadCatch m, MonadLogger m)
  => e
  -> m a
  -> m a
(<??) err a = a `catchAll` (\e -> $(logErrorSH) e >> throwError err)
infixr 0 <??
```

that catches all exceptions, logs the nature of the exception, and then throws (in my case, since my `App` type has an instance of `MonadError ServantErr`) a `ServantErr`.

My handler is something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.Catch
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import qualified Network.AWS as AWS
import           Servant

import App.Types
import App.Db


copy :: Copy -> App Text
copy (Copy user bucket srcKey tgtKey) = do
  err400 <?? runDb (insertRecord $ User user bucket srcKey tgtKey)

  catch (err500 <?? liftIO $ do
    env <- AWS.newEnv AWS.Discover
    void . AWS.runResourceT . AWS.runAWS env $ copyFiles bucket srcKey tgtKey
    return "OK") (\(e :: ServantErr) -> rollback e user)
  where rollback e u = runDb (deleteRecord u) >> throwError e
```

To test the logic, I moved my AWS credentials file, expecting that the inner AWS action would throw an [`InvalidFileError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amazonka-1.5.0/docs/Network-AWS-Auth.html#v:InvalidFileError), then `(<??)` would convert it to a `ServantErr`, then `catch` would catch this `ServantErr` and enact the rollback function.  What happens instead is that the insert succeeds, the `InvalidFileError` is logged, but then the rollback never occurs (i.e., the record still exists in the database after execution).  This `deleteRecord` function is used elsewhere successfully, so I can be sure it's not an issue with its definition.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `App` type is ultimately an [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html), the problem could be that the `MonadError` and `MonadCatch` instances for `ExceptT` are mismatched:

- The `MonadError` instance throws errors as the `e` in `ExceptT e`
- The `MonadCatch` intance catches exceptions in the *underlying monad*, not `ExceptT e` errors.

The [instance definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.1/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html) for `MonadCatch (ExceptT e m)` is:

```
-- | Catches exceptions from the base monad.
instance MonadCatch m => MonadCatch (ExceptT e m) where
   catch (ExceptT m) f = ExceptT $ catch m (runExceptT . f)
```

[`ServantErr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.14.1/docs/Servant-Server.html#t:ServantErr) has an [`Exception`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:Exception) instance, so it can be thrown as both.

---

**Edit**: The "exceptions" class `MonadMask` provides the [`onError`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.1/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#v:onError) function, that even for `ExceptT` is quite well-behaved: it runs the cleanup action both in the case of `ExceptT e` exceptions *and* regular exceptions:

> Run an action only if an error is thrown in the main action. Unlike
>   onException, this works with every kind of error, not just exceptions.
>   For example, if f is an ExceptT computation which aborts with a Left,
>   the computation onError f g will execute g, while onException f g will
>   not.

It is a better option than `catch` for handling the rollback.

Comment: Hmm, okay.  I think I understand.  My `App a` is a `ReaderT Config (LoggingT (ExceptT ServantErr IO)) a` with instances for `MonadError`, `MonadCatch`, and `MonadThrow` automatically derived.  Will I need to write a custom instance for any or all of those?  Or how can I otherwise ensure that the exceptions are caught in the monad they're thrown in?

Comment: Perhaps you could modify `(<??)` in two ways: add `Exception e` and `MonadThrow m` constraints and, before using `catch` on the monadic action, use `catchError` from `MonadError` and re-throw any error found using functions from `MonadThrow`. The idea is to convert the errors into something `MonadCatch` could handle. Still, this mix of error-handling typeclasses feels a bit inelegant. Perhaps it would make sense to shift to an exceptions-only solution.

Comment: Thanks for your additional edit!  I'll give `onError` a shot.

Comment: So, using `onError` rather than `catch` in my handler does appear to do the trick.  I do agree though, now that I've thought a bit more about it, that mixing `MonadError` and `MonadThrow/Catch` seems wrong (and caused this whole confusion in the first place).  However, if I change my `throwError`s to `throwM` this causes the error to not propagate back to the client, e.g., an exception is thrown and the response is a 500, where if I use `throwError err400`, for instance, the proper response is created.

Comment: Would one way to make this nicer be to use `throwM` everywhere and in the handlers, `catch` the error and then use `throwError` on it?